# HighCharts tooltip pointFormat not updating label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts, chartkick

I cannot seem to get the tooltip value label to change using the `tooltip: { pointFormat: "custom label"}` option.

I'm integrating Highcharts in the chartkick gem, and I've ensured that chartkick is indeed using the highcharts adapter. The other library options work such as `xAxis` and `yAxis`.

Here is the code in question:

```
column_chart @registrations.joins(:clinic).group("clinics.name").count,
              title: "Registrations Per Clinic",
              library: {
                  tooltip: {
                      pointFormat: "Registrations: <b>{point.y}</b>"
                  },
                  xAxis: {
                      title: { text: "Clinic" }
                  },
                  yAxis: {
                      allowDecimals: false,
                      title: { text: "Number of Registrations" }
                  }
              }
```

No matter what the tooltip renders with the word Value
[image]

Comment: Hi @mtprogrammer, Please try to define the option on a series level. API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.tooltip

Comment: Unfortunately, no cigar on that suggestion. I tried many variations of series and plotOptions.

Comment: So it is a problem with `chartkick`. The option works correctly with basic Highcharts: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dm0yc4nq/

Answer (score 0):

You can try tooltip.formatter : [Documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter)

Comment: I would totally try this, but I cannot utilized (easily) any of the configuration options that are callback functions while using Chartkick gem. https://github.com/ankane/chartkick/issues/60